# POSIX TimeZone String From Swift TimeZone

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, posix

Is there a way to get a POSIX TimeZone string from the TimeZone data in Swift?

I've looked into the TimeZone functions (`isDaylightSaving()`,`nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition()`, `daylightSavingTimeOffset()`) but they don't quite give me enough information to convert it into something like `TZ=CST6CDT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00`.

I.e. I am missing what the general occurrence of DST is, for example the last Sunday in March, rather than the specific next date that `nextDalightSavingTimeTransition()` gives me.

Would it be a case of just getting a list of TimeZone identifiers against their POSIX TimeZone string, hardcoded in an array/dictionary?

Comment: If you haven't yet, please read the section titled "POSIX style time zones" in [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  In particular note that a POSIX time zone string _cannot_ represent the full fidelity of many time zones.

Comment: Personally, I would advise using them only for lightweight devices (IoT, etc.) where the device can't have a tzdb instance.  In that scenario, you can create a POSIX string from a server that does have the full tzdb, for use on the device within a specific time period.  Such use cases are suitable for getting the valid _current_ local time offset - but not for historical timestamps.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I understand your point, however the device we have to pass in the time zone string to set the time zone of the device is a 3rd party one we have no control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extension to `TimeZone` that provides a `posixDescription`. Much of this code is based on information for the [`TZ` environment variable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).

```swift
extension TimeZone {
    var posixDescription: String {
        if let nextDate = nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition, let afterDate = nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after: nextDate) {
            // This timezone observes DST

            // Get the transition dates to/from standard/DST
            let stdDate: Date
            let dstDate: Date
            if isDaylightSavingTime(for: nextDate) {
                stdDate = afterDate
                dstDate = nextDate
            } else {
                stdDate = nextDate
                dstDate = afterDate
            }

            // Append the standard abbreviation
            var res = posixAbbreviation(for: stdDate)
            // Append the standard offset
            res += posixOffset(for: stdDate)
            // Append the DST abbreviation
            res += posixAbbreviation(for: dstDate)

            // Append the DST offset if it's not 1 hour different
            let diff = secondsFromGMT(for: stdDate) - secondsFromGMT(for: dstDate)
            if abs(diff) != 3600 {
                res += posixOffset(for: dstDate)
            }

            // Get month, weekday ordinal, weekday, hour, minutes, and second
            // weekday gets returned as 1-based but we need 0-based
            // The hour is based on the post-transition time but we need the pre-transition time
            var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            cal.timeZone = self
            let stdcomps = cal.dateComponents([.month, .weekdayOrdinal, .weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: stdDate)
            let dstcomps = cal.dateComponents([.month, .weekdayOrdinal, .weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: dstDate)

            res += String(format: ",M%d.%d.%d/%d:%02d:%02d", dstcomps.month!, dstcomps.weekdayOrdinal!, dstcomps.weekday! - 1, dstcomps.hour! - 1, dstcomps.minute!, dstcomps.second!)
            res += String(format: ",M%d.%d.%d/%d:%02d:%02d", stdcomps.month!, stdcomps.weekdayOrdinal!, stdcomps.weekday! - 1, stdcomps.hour! + 1, stdcomps.minute!, stdcomps.second!)

            return res
        } else {
            // This timezone does not observe DST
            return "\(posixAbbreviation())\(posixOffset())"
        }
    }

    private func posixAbbreviation(for date: Date = Date()) -> String {
        let abrev = abbreviation(for: date) ?? "<UNK>" // We never actually get "<UNK>" for any TimeZone identifier
        // Many abbreviations come in the form "GMT+X" or "GMT-X"
        return abrev.hasPrefix("GMT") ? "GMT" : abrev
    }

    private func posixOffset(for date: Date = Date()) -> String {
        // The POSIX offset is the opposite of the GMT offset
        let secs = 0 - secondsFromGMT(for: date)
        let h = secs / 3600
        let m = abs(secs) % 3600 / 60
        let s = abs(secs) % 60

        // Show the hour, only show the minutes and seconds if non-zero
        return "\(h)\(m == 0 && s == 0 ? "" : ":\(String(format: "%02d", m))")\(s == 0 ? "" : ":\(String(format: "%02d", s))")"
    }
}
```

The `abbreviation` method of the `TimeZone` class seems to return "GMT" +/- offset for many timezone identifiers instead of the timezone's actual abbreviation. Not much to be done about that.

The code seems to work in general but it likely gives some incorrect values for some timezones. I don't know how to verify the definitive result in all cases.

For the "America/Chicago" timezone it results in:

> CST6CDT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00

as expected.

Comment: This is great, thank you! The .weekdayOrdinal was what I was missing when trying to convert to the format.